# Jquery .post() html code

Tags: jquery, post, character-encoding

I'm having a very strange problem.

I have a form with an input field for the user to copy-paste Vimeo's embed code.
The form is then submitted via ajax.

The problem is that when I write something else than the embed code in the input form, it works fine.
When I paste the input code, it returns a "Page Not Found" error. I've narrow it down to two characters. When I type "><" I get the error. If I type "<>", the script passes.

The HTML form is ok so I'll just post my javascript code. (I use jQuery)

```
          //submit the video form
          function submitVideoForm() {
            var $inputs = $j('#form-add-video :input');
            var values = {};
            //loop through all the inputs and add them in an object
            $j($inputs).each(function() {
                values[this.name] = $j(this).val();
            });

            $j.post("http://www.mysite.com/admin/plugin/media/add_video/", values,
               function(data){
                    if (data != 'false') {
                        console.log('Worked');
                    }
                    else { 
                        console.log('Failed');
                    };
             }, 'json');

          }
```

When I look at what's posted with firebug, I can see that the data is escaped

```
media%5Barticleid%5D=355&media%5Bembed_code%5D=%3Ciframe+src%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fplayer.vimeo.com%2Fvideo%2F21350265%3Ftitle%3D0%26amp%3Bbyline%3D0%26amp%3Bportrait%3D0%22+width%3D%22398%22+height%3D%22224%22+frameborder%3D%220%22%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E
```

I've tried using escape(), same problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Already tried **encodeURIComponent/decodeURIComponent** function?

Comment: Where are you getting this 'Page Not Found' error? When you try to submit the form? Can you provide us with the URL that it cannot find (removing your personal site)

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the error: http://i.imgur.com/1Aw3C.jpg. Here's the screenshot of the same script but different value in the input: http://i.imgur.com/NEAwY.jpg.
Just so you know, I did try with the solutions below (encodeURIComponent, escape, etc). The string is encoded but I still get the error.

Comment: Is it possible the server sees it as a security threat and is blocking it when it sees %3E%3C (just a thought)

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I'm past this problem. I never found the solution, just updated the way the user added a video.

Answer (score 0):

HTML tags can mess with your code. Replace it with its HTML entity equivalent. **[Snippet](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/htmlentities-for-javascript/)**

Comment: Although it does what it says it does, this did not fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try [serializing](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) your data, since you are using jQuery.

Replace `$inputs` and `values` with `var values = $j('#form-add-video').serialize();` and remove  the function looping through the inputs. `.serialize` will grab all of them for you.

OR, you could try [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp)

Ex: `values[this.name] = encodeURIComponent($j(this).val());`

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent) for further discussion on escape vs encodeURI() vs encodeURIComponent.

Comment: Hi John, I tried it and it didn't help. It encoded the string properly but still got the "page not found" error.

Comment: Edited my answer to try .serialize()

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use serialize because it's not really a form. The reason is that it's a plugin for a CMS and it's already wrapped inside a <form>. I just need to post a small part of it.